# Can I deploy multiple WAR archive files to local Tomcat with IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, angular, tomcat, intellij-idea, war

I have two applications with two separate WAR artifacts. One is a WAR exploded directory for my front-end Angular app, and one is a WAR archive file for my back-end Spring REST api. I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA to deploy my front-end to a local Tomcat server and was wondering how, if at all possible, I could configure IntelliJ to run my two artifacts on Tomcat simultaneously. I know I can do this by putting both under Tomcat webapps directory manually, but I was wondering if it was configurable in IntelliJ, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do that.

> If you are using Ultimate, you can create a "Local Tomcat" run
>   configuration in Project1,  and go to the "Deployment" tab and drop in
>   the WAR file for your Project1.   Then drop in the WAR file from your
>   other project (call it Project2) as an External Source.   You would
>   then have both WARs in one run configuration.

This is the answer I found out under  [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206850365-Deploying-and-running-multiple-WARs-on-the-same-instance-of-Tomcat) link.

Comment: This worked very well until I ran into an issue with needing a different environment variable value in the two wars.  I ended up running the independent webservice in a Docker box, and the dependent webservice in IntelliJ.  I don't recall if Eclipse could handle this situation.